# Duplicate function with new div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

how do i duplicate this function to another div?

```
function goto(id, t){   

    //animate to the div id.
    $(".headbox-wrapper").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);

    // remove "active" class from all links inside #nav
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');

    // add active class to the current link
    $(t).addClass('active');    
}
```

With new name and new div, example function2.

Its on the same page as this one, when i copy and just print new script neither of them works which is pretty obvious.

Comment: How is this function called? if I was animating on click say I'd do this: $('.headbox-wrapper, .headbox-wrapper2').click(function(){alert('animate func here');});

Comment: I would say `$(id)` should be replaced with `$("#" + id)` if `id` contains just an id.

Comment: Can you show me what you mean on jsFiddle?

Comment: Where are you getting the values of 'id' & 't'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on Beneto's comment:

```
function goto(id, t){   
    $(".headbox-wrapper, .headbox-wrapper2").animate({"left": -($(id).position().left)}, 600);
    $('#nav a').removeClass('active');
    $(t).addClass('active');    
}
```

Html:

```
<div id='headbox-wrapper'>Click me!</div>
<div id='headbox-wrapper2'>Click me again!</div>
```